# How to set an attribute globally to a field in MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

This the code which implement the mapping in mongoDb

```
public static void MapEntity<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<TEntity>(e =>
    {
        e.AutoMap();
        e.MapIdProperty(u => u.Id)
         .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
         .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
    });
}
```

And I have a field like this in an entity class

```
 [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
 public DateTime Received { get; set; }
```

and I have datetime fields in many entities and I need to apply the   `[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]` to all of them . Is there a way where we can set it as a global  for all datetime fields by using the  BsonClassMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime),
         new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Local));
```

Has resolved my Issue